# Xcode 9.3 and Firebase Crashlytics not working

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I cannot get Firebase Crashlytics to show my crashes of my Xcode iOS Swift app.

- Using Xcode 9.3
- I have manually (not using cocoapods) integrated the Crashlytics SDK
  as specified here:
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0
- I have tested both in the simulator and on the device
- I made both crash (using an own written crash function, but also the supplied crash function), I restarted the device/simulator (because the crash is only transmitted upon the next launch)
- I am not seeing any crashes in the Firebase Crashlytics console, it keeps on saying "Upgrade to Crashlytics for more powerful, realtime crash analysis"
- I can confirm in the xcode debug console logs that the crashlytics is running because I see "[Crashlytics] Version 3.10.1 (129)"
- I disabled bitcode does not change anything...
- I looked in the system console and found:

> default   21:17:49.828801 +0200   nsurlsessiond   [9
> reports.crashlytics.com:443 stream, pid: 72896, traffic class: 200,
> tls, indefinite] cancelled
> [9.1 463924B9-A95E-44FB-AA19-CFE9616E37E0 192.168.99.209.59507<->54.243.248.96:443]
> Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
> Duration: 2.586s, DNS @0.000s took 0.027s, TCP @0.028s took 0.110s, TLS took 0.255s
> bytes in/out: 6086/30045, packets in/out: 7/23, rtt: 0.092s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0

- Its like 9 crashes are pending/hanging? What is this cancelled?
- I figured, maybe it's because there are no dsyms uploaded so I checked the build process in Xcode and found:

> 2018-04-16 21:55:35.270 uploadDSYM[77897:3132594] Fabric.framework/run
> 1.7.0 (208) 2018-04-16 21:55:35.278 uploadDSYM[77897:3132594] Firebase mode detected. 2018-04-16 21:55:35.278 uploadDSYM[77897:3132594] Using
> API Key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 2018-04-16 21:55:35.279
> uploadDSYM[77897:3132594] Launched uploader in validation mode

- What does this "launched uploader in validation mode" mean? Does it mean that the dsym upload is not working?
- I wanted to manually upload the dsyms using: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?authuser=0 but the fabric.framework does not contain any upload-symbols? The Google documentation wrong? I can see an "uploadDSYM" but this does not seam to have the same options/arguments so I guess it's not this one...?

Comment: I'd recommend contacting [support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). I can't tell for sure if that's a bug, but at minimum it's a feature request for better error messages since that log doesn't help you as the user figure out what's happening.

Comment: Yes will file a report but was hoping that somebody already solved it...

Comment: Hi! Todd from Crashlytics. Please email us with your bundle ID and we'll get you back up and running :)

Comment: @ToddBurner I figured it out with you asking the bundle id I verified it and yes... the bundle id specified in the portal was not the one I was using in the app...

Comment: @ToddBurner however the missing "upload-symbols" script in the swift framework is an issue; can you have a look at this?

Comment: @ToddBurner, please see my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50479344/crashlytics-packets-not-getting-through-to-fabric-io

Answer (score 1):

Based on Todd's input (he is from Crashlytics) I found the issue.
The reason was that the bundleid specified in the Firebase Console for the app was not the one that I was using in the actual app! So I deleted the old app (with the wrong bundle id) and re-created it with the correct bundleid in the Firebase Console and now its working.

*Note: it is not possible to change the bundleid once the app is created apparently.*